# Parse file contents into array of section headings and section lines

Tags: php, arrays, regex, parsing, multidimensional-array

I've got a string like this:

```
####################
Section One
####################
Data A
Data B


####################
   Section Two
####################
Data C
Data D

etc.
```

I want to parse it into something like:

```
$arr(
    'Section One' => array('Data A', 'Data B'),
    'Section Two' => array('Data C', 'Data D')
)
```

At first I tried this:

```
$sections = preg_split("/(\r?\n)(\r?\n)#/", $file_content);
```

The problem is, the file isn't perfectly clean: sometimes there are different numbers of blank lines between the sections, or blank spaces between data rows.

The section head pattern itself seems to be relatively consistent:

```
####################
   Section Title
####################
```

The number of #'s is probably consistent, but I don't want to count on it. The white space on the title line is pretty random.

Once I have it split into sections, I think it'll be pretty straightforward, but any help writing a killer reg ex to get it there would be appreciated. (Or if there's a better approach than reg ex...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to quickly wrote this up:

```
<?php
$text = <<<EOT
####################
Section One
####################
Data B.Thing=bar#
.##.#%#

####################
   Empty Section!
####################
####################
   Last section
####################

Blah

   Blah C# C# C#

EOT;
$entries = array_chunk(
   preg_split("/^#+/m", $text, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY),
   2
);
$sections = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
  $key = trim($entry[0]);
  $value = preg_split("/\n/", $entry[1], null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  $sections[$key] = $value;
} 
print_r($sections);
?>
```

The output is: ([as run on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/59Y3V))

```
Array
(
    [Section One] => Array
        (
            [0] => Data B.Thing=bar#
            [1] => .##.#%#
        )

    [Empty Section!] => Array
        (
        )

    [Last section] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blah
            [1] =>    Blah C# C# C#
        )

)
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! But it doesn't quite work. :( It seems to choke on non-alpha characters in the data rows, which all of my data rows have, since they're name value pairs like "foo.bar=baz" http://ideone.com/u3xYo

Comment: @sprugman, well, I wasn't sure what the data pattern is, but if you can guarantee that it will never contain `#`, (e.g. no `"C# is awesome!"` or anything like that), then just use `[^#]+` instead of `[\w\s]+` http://ideone.com/zrx9n

Comment: how 'bout if I guarantee that no line except the section delimiters will ever start with a #?

Comment: @sprugman: check out latest revision. Tell me if there's anything else I can do.

Comment: thanks for all your help. I found another way to break it (unless I wasn't looking at the latest -- it seems to change the url every time you edit): http://ideone.com/2TOfp

Comment: I had to add a (\r?) to deal with the CRLFs of the source, but that seems to be working. Thanks!! http://ideone.com/V4X0D

Comment: @sprugman: you're the first person on stackoverflow who've went back and forth with me on ideone.com; I think this is neat!!!

Comment: It worked pretty well, apart from having to update the url every time. (I wonder if they have a setting for that.) It might be nice to update your answer with the final version.... (Oh wait, maybe you did already. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd take a multi-step approach:

- split into section headings/content
- parse each heading/content pair into the desired array structure

Here's an example, split into multiple lines so you can track what is going on:

<sup>Note the lack of sanity checking, this *assumes* nice, neat heading/content groups. 
The regex was written for brevity and may or may not be sufficient for your needs.</sup>

```
// Split string on a line of text wrapped in lines of only #'s
$parts = preg_split('/^#+$\R(.+)\R^#+$/m', $subject, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
// Tidy up leading/trailing whitespace for each heading/content-block
$parts = array_map('trim', $parts);
// Chunk into array("heading", "content")
$parts = array_chunk($parts, 2);

// Create the final array
$sections = array();
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $sections[$part[0]] = explode("\n", $part[1]);
}

// Lets take a look
var_dump($sections);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I wound up going back and forth with @polygenelubricants....

Comment: Oookkkk. I'll never quite understand this place. :-/

Answer (score 0):

> any help writing a killer reg ex to get it there would be appreciated

...I have your killer regex pattern -- it relies on the `\G` (continue) metacharacter to match the variably occurring lines of text after each section heading.

This technique is more optimal than previous answers because there is a single `preg_` call and **zero** iterated function calls.

Sample Input:

```
$fileContents = <<<TEXT
####################
Section One
####################
Data A
Data B


####################
   Section Two
####################
Data C
Data D
Data E

####################
   Section Three
####################
Data F
TEXT;
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6mtjV))

```
preg_match_all(
    '~(?:
        ^\#{3,}\R
        \h*(\S+(?:\h\S+)*)\h*\R
        \#{3,}
      |
        \G(?!\A)
      )
      \R
      (?!\#{3,})(.+)
     ~mx',
    $fileContents,
    $out,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);

foreach ($out as $set) {
    $heading = $set[1] ?: $heading;
    $result[$heading][] = $set[2];
}
var_export($result ?? 'No qualifying data');
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Section One' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Data A',
    1 => 'Data B',
  ),
  'Section Two' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Data C',
    1 => 'Data D',
    2 => 'Data E',
  ),
  'Section Three' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Data F',
  ),
)
```

Breakdown:

```
~               #starting pattern delimiter
(?:             #start non-capturing group 1
  ^             #match the start of a line
  \#{3,}        #match 3 or more hash symbols
  \R            #match a newline sequence
  \h*           #match space or tab, zero or more times
  (             #start capture group 1
    \S+         #match one or more non-whitespace characters
    (?:         #start non-capturing group 2
      \h        #match space or tab
      \S+       #one or more non-whitespace characters
    )*          #end capture group 2, permit zero or more occurrences
  )             #end capture group 1
  \h*           #match space or tab, zero or more times
  \R            #match a newline sequence
  \#{3,}        #match 3 or more hash symbols
  |             #or
  \G(?!\A)      #continue matching but disallow starting from start of string
)               #end non-capturing group 1
\R              #match a newline sequence
(?!             #start negative lookahead
  \#{3,}        #match 3 or more hash symbols
)               #end negative lookahead
(.+)            #match the whole line excluding the trailing newline characters
~               #ending pattern delimiter
m               #pattern modifier: demand that ^ matches start of lines
x               #pattern modifier: allow meaningless whitespaces in pattern for improved readability
```

...this was a fun necropost.